# Cyberoam UTM console accessible from outside network Is it secure?

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall

A organisation is running Cyberoam UTM for securing their network from malicious activity from outside network and inside network also. Now, company has given a feasibility to his administrator to access admin console of cyberoam UTM from outside network instead of LAN segment. Although, company is running admin console on https://publicip

FYI, A organisation has already created VPN for all remotely activities except this activity.

So using https to access UTM from outside network is secure or administrator should login through VPN tunnel to access UTM console from outside network?

Please reply asap

Comment: I wouldn't allow access to it from the outside.

Comment: Running on https and allowing access through VPN tunnel would be secure? @ joeqwerty

Comment: Making it accessible only from the LAN through a VPN connection? Yes, that would strike me as being more secure.

Comment: In case of emergency, using "https" and making it accessible from WAN through VPN connection could also be secure? @joeqwerty